# How to select an element from a menu using Webdriver Selenium ? The Menu drop down shows up on Mouse Over?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

How to select an element from a menu using **Webdriver Selenium** ? The **Menu drop down** shows up on **Mouse Over**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check it in two ways:
1) first way is to use actions builder

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("mnEle")).Click();
sbEle = driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).Click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.MoveToElement(mnEle).Perform();
// Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
Thread.sleep(5000L);
// Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).Click();
```

See [here](http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/)

2) another approach is to click directly needed element using jscript without simulating mouse hover event:

```
String cssLocatorOfTheElement=....//locator of the element to click on    
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssLocatorOfTheElement+"\');");
            stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
            js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

hope this works for you)

Comment: With selenium-java-2.35:

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("user-options"))).click();
                    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("log_out"))).click(driver.findElement(By.id("log_out")));
                builder.perform();

If the simple .click() does not work, pass the Element to it, even if the cursor was moved there already.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate mouseOver event and then select element you can like that:

```
var elementToShowMenu = Driver.FindElement(Byl.Id("some id")); 
new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(elementToShowMenu).Release(elementToShowMenu).Build().Perform();
var menuElement = Driver.FindElement(Byl.Id("your menu id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I click a invisible anchor link on a  tag: a link that is generated dynamically by Javascript:

```
public static void mouseClickByLocator( String cssLocator ) {
     String locator = cssLocator;
     WebElement el = driver.findElement( By.cssSelector( locator ) );
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
     builder.moveToElement( el ).click( el );
     builder.perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;
mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("insert selector here"));
submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("insert selector here"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnuElement).perform();
// Pause 2 Seconds for submenu to be displayed
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); //Pause 2 seconds
// Clicking on the Hidden submnuElement
submnuElement.click();
```